# INSERT INTO Multiple Tables with one Submit

Tags: php, sql-server

I have 2 Tables that I want to submit into at the same time, both of these have unique AI ID's. I use the Primary Key in table A as a Foreign Key in Table B. Is there a way so that when I submit I can get the newly created ID from Table A and use it a Foreign Key in Table B?

I have tried this but nothing gets inserted into the Second (Results) Table,

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "
        DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID INT)
        INSERT INTO Parts (PartNumber, Description, Manufacturer, TestDate, VendorDescription, ReceiptNo)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.PartID INTO @OutputTbl(ID)
        VALUES
        ('".$_POST['PartNumberSubmit']."','".$_POST['DescriptionSubmit']."','".$_POST['ManufacturerSubmit']."','".$_POST['TestDateSubmit']."','".$_POST['VendorDescriptionSubmit']."','".$_POST['ReceiptNoSubmit']."')
        DECLARE @Id INT
        SET @Id = (SELECT Id from @OutputTbl)
        INSERT INTO Results (Test, Result, PartID)
        VALUES ('Some', 'Thing', @Id)");
```

Comment: `select @@IDENTITY as id` will give you the last ID on SQL servers (MSSQL, which you have tagged the question with).

Comment: Last insert Id comes to mind if using PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php I also would use transactions.

Comment: You can get the last identity value assigned in the current scope using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. For example, `INSERT INTO dbo.TableA ...;;INSERT INTO dbo.TableB VALUES(SCOPE_IDENTITY()...);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use OUTPUT

```
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO tab_1(Col1, Col2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @OutputTbl(ID) --the newly created Id
VALUES ('Yatrix', '1234')

DECLARE @Id INT 
SET @Id = (SELECT Id from @OutputTbl)

INSERT INTO tab_2 (Col1, Col2, tab_1_FK)
VALUES ('some', 'thing', @Id)
```

Comment: Tried using this code to achieve it, but nothing gets inserted into the second table

Comment: Is there a value in the table variable?